# Visual Studio : ASPX : corrupted 'IIf' syntax : strange error

Tags: asp.net, iif

The following declaration in my ASPX file contains an ERROR within the **IIf()** arguments...

```
<br /><asp:Label ID="lblvalLOF_IS_DUE"  runat="server" 
Text='<%# IIf((Eval("aIsLOF_Due") = "True"), "&#9745;", "&#9744;")%>'
style="font-size: 2em;"/>
```

The error that shows in the [Error-List] window is:

> Argument not specified for parameter 'FalsePart' of  'Public Function
>   IIf(Expression As Boolean, TruePart As Object, FalsePart As Object) As
>   Object'.

There is a "squiggly" underline from **IIF** to the end-quote of **#9745;"** indicating that there is a syntax error within the **IIf** arguments.

I think there is some conflict with the declaration of the special-characters -- either QUOTEs or AMPERSAND or # symbol.

Any guidance will be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks good at a first glance. Let's start small - try just to remove ampersand and hash symbol and see if that works. It won't output exactly what you need, but will give some troubleshooting info

Comment: Agreed, I think the # symbol is to blame..

Comment: remove `;` seems in vb it some special, it interesting but if you run this as is you get correct work, seems error in vs

Comment: Removing <semicolon> did the trick -- thanks a million.

Comment: This was the answer.  Thanks Grundy.

Comment: @JohnD, but i don't know **why** it did the trick :-D also seems like something with vs parsing if it work with semicolon when you move it to code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK friends...I simplified the aspx code and removed the server code as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblvalLOF_IS_DUE"  runat="server" 
Text='<%# IIf((Eval("aIsLOF_Due") = "True"), "&#9745", "&#9744") & ";"  %>'
style="font-size: 3em;"/>
```

I returned to the original IIf() coding but separated the semi-colon from the  values being returned by the IIf() with concatenating the semi-colon after the IIf(). This construct should also work if setting colors conditionally in the aspx code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is related to special cases `"&...;"` in aspx parsing inside VS.

Interesting that in C# i have error

> Error 1|  Newline in constant

and this also fixed after removing semicolon, so this working sample

```
<asp:Label ID="lblvalLOF_IS_DUE"  runat="server" Text='<%# IIf((Eval("aIsLOF_Due") == "True"), "&#9745", "&#9744")%>' style="font-size: 2em;"/>
```

and same for C#

```
<asp:Label ID="lblvalLOF_IS_DUE"  runat="server" Text='<%# ((Eval("aIsLOF_Due") = "True")? "&#9745": "&#9744")%>' style="font-size: 2em;"/>
```